# html/css formatting for middle image and four divs on outside

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble and need assistance. Essentially, I want a center image div and four divs around the center image with text. Also, when I collapse the page width, I want them to all float centered below one another. Imagine a smartphone image in the middle of the screen and four text blocks (two top and two bottom). Additionally (to complicate things, ha) I want the left top and bottom text blocks to have right aligned text and the right top and bottom text blocks to have left aligned text. When the page collapses, I want all text to be centered. Thank you very much for any assistance!

The problem I have with my existing code: I cannot move the text blocks exactly where I want. I don't want them specifically at the top and bottom. Also, I am having trouble with aligning the text properly.

This is what I have so far:

```css
#solutions2Header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.solutionSection2:after { /*clear float*/
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.solutionSection2 > div {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 850px) { /*breakpoint*/
  .solutionSection2 > div {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.solutions2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom:  500px;
}

#iphonexCenter {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#bottomBox {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="solutions2">
  <h2 id="solutions2Header">Highlighted Features</h2>
  <div class="solutionSection2">
    <div>
      <p>Charges stored in one <br>place.</p>
      <p><br>Provides peace of mind by<br>syncing and storing your charges<br>automatically.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x600" id="iphonexCenter" alt="iPhone X Image" height="600" width="300" style="margin: 0 auto">
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>Individual and team<br>messaging.</p>
      <p><br>100% HIPAA compliant text<br>messaging at the tip of your fingers.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="solutionSection2">
    <div id="bottomBox">
      <p>Track daily work<br>progress.</p>
      <p><br>Intellegently helps locate<br>missing charges and provides a score<br>card to ensure all charges are entered.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p></p>
    </div>

    <div id="bottomBox">
      <p>Care coordination<br>alerts.</p>
      <p><br>Be in the know. We can alert <br>your providers via admit/discharge
      <br> notifications, stat, routine consults,<br> and more.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you specify exactly what your problem is with the existing code?

Comment: Done, I added the problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need support for old browser I would go with flex box. It's quite easy. You can find complete guide to it here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/